# Adding an in game menu android game

Tags: android

I have a game (Surface Activity) and a menu. While the game is running the menu is opened as a new activity, an object selected and its id is passed back to the game using finish() to close the menu. How do I set the id from the menu without creating a new Game?

I cant use = new Game() at it will reset the game?

Comment: When you say menu, do you mean an Android Menu, or your own activity that acts as a menu?

Comment: Instead of destroying/recreating your game activity which is slow, try using a PopupWindow?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should save the game state when you leave the activity the game is currently playing in. There are several ways of doing so, have a look at this question: 
[Saving Game state Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285064/saving-game-state-android)
I personally would rather incorporate the menu of the game in the same activity as the game, since it would make things easier and from a designing point of view is acceptable, when developing with a game engine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use intents for passing parameter(check intent.putExtra and getIntent()) for simple datas.Like setting options.
Also [check shared preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for more complex datas, for instance :to turn previous game.